# Change the tag name for all resourcegroups under subscription

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I need to change the tag key but the value should remain same. For example I have a tag called  "SkuId =1234". I need to change the key value to  "SystemId =1234" .Tried something like below.. Didn't work...Any suggestions?

```
$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup
foreach($resourcegroup in $resourceGroups){
$Tags = (Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup).Tags
$Tags += @{"SystemId"=$tags.oldtag}
$Tags.Remove('oldtag')
$resourceGroup.resourcegroupname |Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag $Tags
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$Tags = (Get-AzResourceGroup).Tags
$Tags += @{"SystemId"=$tags.oldtag}
$Tags.Remove('oldtag')
Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Tag $Tags
```

Comment: Each resourcegroup has different value for the same key. Does this works accordingly?

Comment: well, if you have an outer loop over this - yes

Comment: Edited Question by adding outer loop. That works? Want to be sure before running because I have 400 resource groups once changed cant get old values

Comment: you can always limit your script by making it run only against a single resource group

Comment: also, there should be a `-Whatif`option that you can use together with `-Debug` to test the snippet, but your loop looks reasonable, except it should be something like `$resourceGroup.resourcegroupname` I dont remember the exact property name

Comment: Ur script just creating a tag but it's not taking the value from old tag

Comment: it should, unless you have a typo